# DAX: Calculating column group share of total

Tags: powerbi, dax

Noob question that I couldn't find an answer for online.. I have a column with months, and would like to create a new column with the proportion of the occurrences of that rows particular month. How can I do this? Thanks for your time
e.g.

```
Month    New column
January  50%
January  50%
February 25%
April    25%
```

Answer (score 1):

found the answer elsewhere https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Percent-of-column-Total/td-p/213147

```
Perent of Total = 
DIVIDE (
    COUNTA(Sheet1[CIP2]),
    CALCULATE ( COUNTA(Sheet1[CIP2]), ALLEXCEPT (Sheet1,Sheet1[Week]) )
)
```